# Robolectric with existing android maven project

Tags: java, android, maven, junit, robolectric

I've checked out different sollutions but could not fit any to this issue.

Actually there is android project which has beed imported to android studio as a maven project. It looks like :

```
.
├── assets
├── gen-external-apklibs
├── keystores
├── manifest
├── out
├── res
├── src
│   └── com
│       └── project
│           └── 
└── target
    ├──
```

We wish to implements `junit` tests with `robolectric` `framework`. We want to do 'store' them in the same(project) `directory`(where to put them and how to name in upper tree), but they could be started from command line.

AFAIK to write them in the same `IDE`(android studio), there should be jUnit and `robolectric` properly imported in *android studio*. This is what we would like to achieve to go TDD:

```
-write test in the same ide 
-write code in the same ide 
-run test from cmd, or as a separate maven profile
-later integrate it with Contunuous Integration like Jenkins
```

If not clear enough please provide your own sollutions. Any additional knowledge appriciated.

Recently we've added the dependency in `pom.xml` with:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also added junit:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

`mvn` build ends with success but writing simple:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SimpleTest {
}
```

does not recognize `RobolectricTestRunner.class` from robolectric. So the general question is how to set up the environment?

Regards

This http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/ is good tutorial with the same issue, but it is based on gradle.

Comment: Are you specifying the testSourceDirectory in your pom file?

Comment: Nope, just only that what I've mentioned.

Comment: Then the problem might be that maven doesn't know that your test files are indeed test (and not normal source) files, because it doesn't know where to find your test files. 
If that's the case, it makes sense that they won't be able to use a dependency that has been marked as available only for test.

Comment: So depending on <scope>test</scope> selected in pom.xml what should be changed depending on the directory (test or another) ?

Comment: Setting the scope to test for a dependency means that it will be available for building and running your tests, but will not be available or included in the main build (so in this case, cannot be used by your application code and will not be added to the APK). So your scope is correct for robolectric and should probably be test for JUnit as well, since these are libraries only for tests. What you also need to do is to tell maven where your tests are located, try doing that with testSourceDirectory.